# Подскажите, можно ли на android сделать в filepicker выбор файла json формата, если можно, то расскажите как?

Tags: java, android, json, файлы

У меня есть приложение которое сразу уже открывает готовый json файл, но мне нужно чтобы я мог выбирать какой именно

Answer (score 0):

Вызовите интент ACTION_GET_CONTENT через startActivityForResult. Ему можно передать нужные вам типы файлов, чтобы другие не отображались. Вызовится стандартное системное приложения для селекта файлов. [Пример](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/14425/showing-a-file-chooser-and-reading-the-result)